# How can I getting return '' if object[3] return value is 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I want getting `''`, if `object[3]` return value is `IndexError: list index out of range`

Is it possible?

The code I'm using is:

```
object = [4,5]
print(object[3] if object[3] is not None else '')
```

This error is what I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    object[3] if object[3] is not None else ''
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Hmm...you can only use something like `print(object[3] if len(object) >= 3 else '')`. Otherwise you have to use a `try...except` block. Because Python will raise an error instead of return `None` when you're trying to access an index which isn't in the list.

Comment: `>=` should be `>`. Otherwise, if there are 3 items, it will raise `IndexError`.

Comment: @falsetru: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Ah, yeah. Forgot that `object[3]` is the 4th element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the list before access the item:

```
>>> lst = [4,5]
>>> lst[3] if len(lst) > 3 and lst[3] is not None else ''
''

>>> lst = [4,5,6,7,8]
>>> lst[3] if len(lst) > 3 and lst[3] is not None else ''
7
```

BTW, [`object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) is a builtin type. Using `object` as a variable will shadow it. Use other name if possible.

Comment: Thanks!!  If it is no Index of Array(IndexError: list index out of range), return`  ' '  ` . Is possible??